# jQuery scroll not being triggered

Tags: jquery, events, scroll, jquery-events

I'm trying to do a parallax scroll tutorial (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/). I cannot get the background position CSS to change via jQuery. I've been able to deduce that the scroll handler isn't being called. I have this alert that doesn't trigger when I scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    alert('Handler for scroll called');
});
```

When I do the alert outside of this function, it is called. So I know jQuery is being called right (this is all inside a .ready() function). Any ideas?

EDIT

I can't even call the scroll handler manually. For example, this works:

```
$('*').click(function(){
    alert('handler called');
});
```

But this does not:

```
$('*').click(function(){
    $(window).scroll();
}); // Remember I set an alert up above for when the scroll handler was called
```

SECOND EDIT, ENTIRE JS FILE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: 50% 10 });
        }); 
    });
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        alert('Handler for scroll called');
    });
    $('*').click(function(){
        $(window).scroll();
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're scrolling the window ?

Comment: What you posted - should work --http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/UeBMR/1/

Comment: @adeneo I am scrolling. I think it's the window, I don't have anything else like divs or anything set to scroll.

Comment: @MohammadAdil Yes, I agree it should be working. But, it's not. That's why I've come here. :)

Comment: when you click that function, it doesn't call the scroll function. Would you mind posting the whole Javascript file

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use? `.on()` has been added in 1.7, your code works when i test it using jQuery 1.8 and higher.

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert I am using 1.9.1 in the latest version of chrome.

Comment: Do you have any errors when using JavaScript console?

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert Yes, it says uncaught ReferenceError: $window not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$window.scrollTop needed to be changed to $(window).scrollTop.